# Linear indepedence and probabilisitic independence over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, independence

Let $v_1,...,v_k \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$ be linearly independent vectors, and let $x$ be a uniform random vector in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. For each $1 \leq i \leq k$, define the random variable $Y_i = \langle v_i, x \rangle = v_i \cdot x$.

Are the $Y_i$'s then mutually independent?

I know each of the $Y_i$s are uniform in $\mathbb{F}_q$.
To try to prove the statement I tried to prove the contrapositive, i.e. if for some subset $i \in [n]$, and $S \subset [n] \setminus \{i\}$, $\Pr[Y_i=y_i|\bigwedge_{j \in S} Y_j = y_j] \neq 1/q$, then there is some linear relation of the $v_i$s but I am having trouble with that.

On the other hand, I know the converse is true since if there is a linear relation of the $v_i$s, i.e. $v_1 = \lambda_2v_2 +...+\lambda_kv_k$, then, $Y_1$ is determined when conditioned on $Y_2,...,Y_k$ (because of linearity of the inner product).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The result is obvious with $v_i=e_i$. Then take $M\in GL_n(\Bbb{F}_q)$ such that $v_j=Me_j$ so that $Y_i = \langle e_i, M^{-\top} x\rangle$.

Comment: Great point! Thank you :)

Comment: Hmm actually, I'm still a little confused. Is $M^Tx$ also a uniform random vector, and if so, why?

Comment: Because multiplication by $M^{\top}$ is a bijection

Comment: Ahh, right! Thank you so much!